# how to use htaccess redirect to a empty url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

how can I redirect a page with a real url to an url that has no file inside?
Real page adress: about-us/
new page adress: about_us/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about_us/(.*) about-us/$1
```

Comment: Unclear, what do you mean by empty URL. Source and target URLs appear to be same.

Comment: I want to redirect a page to a place that does not have any real folder or file.

Comment: Its still unclear what you actually want to achieve.  Can you please define "a place that does not have a real folder or file" ?

Comment: Forget about the idea that the path component in a URL indicates physical files in the server side file system. That was the case in the early days of the web, but today both things have little in common. Well, maybe still for beginners tutorials, but that's about it. So sure, you can invent any path you like and internally rewrite that to any resource in the local file system you like. Nothing keeps you from doing just that.